# Android appwidget-provider: dynamic width

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I'm creating a simple android widget that will show small images.

I need to be able to set the width of the widget according to the num of images selected.

My widget:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <appwidget-provider
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
        android:minHeight="72dp"
        android:minWidth="72dp"
        android:updatePeriodMillis="0" >
    </appwidget-provider>
```

And the Java class:

```
      public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
      int[] appWidgetIds) {


      SharedPreferences preferences =   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
      if(!url.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
      {
          url = preferences.getString("url", "");
      }

       // Get all ids
       ComponentName thisWidget = new      ComponentName(context,MyWidgetProvider.class);

    int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

    for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {

      RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_layout);


      // Register an onClickListener
      Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);

      intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
      intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);

      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
      remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.open, pendingIntent);
      appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
    }


     }
```

How can I change the `minWidth` and `minHeight` programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's not possible to change minWidth and minHeight programmatically; but you may try to use `resizeMode` to extend the widget layout. I hope this solution helps you.

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="320dp"
    android:minHeight="320dp"
    android:minResizeHeight="160dp"
    android:minResizeWidth="240dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="100"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
    android:autoAdvanceViewId="@+id/list_view"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/preview_image"
    android:resizeMode="vertical|horizontal"
    />
```